# Problems reading form variables in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

**Background**: I've been asked to work on a legacy asp.net application for which there is no documentation and the original programmers are not available for consultation.  I'm primarily a Perl programmer, primarily on *nix systems, so while I've no major problems with the actual logic of the system, I'm getting tied in knots by some of the "bare bones" stuff underneath.

**Outline**: I'm trying to extend an existing aspx form to increase its functionality, the form is part of a system for purchasing telephone numbers.  At the moment, the form when first called shows a list of locations and telephone area codes in an HTML drop-down list, and expects the user to select one.  When a value is selected (or selected and the select button clicked, if JS is disabled) and the form submitted, the page in postback mode then provides an appropriate redirect to a purchase page, with various values set in the query string.  I want to extend the functionality by adding a second row of controls, on the same form, comprising a text box for users to enter an area code, and a "Search" button. The idea is that when a user does this, the system will then do a DB search for that area code, and if a match is found, generate the appropriate redirect to the page selling that area.  All the code is (and will be) in C#.

**The problem**: Having found a lot of useful info here on Stack Overflow on extracting form variables from asp.net forms, I tried to retrieve my new variables using Request.form["variable_name"].  But it soon became clear the values weren't coming through.

Here's the aspx page code for the new bit of the form:

```
<tr>
    <td align='left'><b>STD code:</b></td>
    <td align='left'>
        <asp:TextBox id="STD_Code_Search"
             AutoPostBack="True"
             Columns="7"
             Text=""
             TextMode="SingleLine"
             Wrap="False"
             runat="server"/>
    </td>
        <td><asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Search" /></td>
</tr>
```

I expected to be able to pull those variables back via

```
Button2_Clicked = Request.Form["Button2"]
STD_Code_Search = Request.Form["STD_Code_Search"]
```

However nothing ever came through.  Based on more searches, I found this code to display all the variables coming into the form:

```
    foreach(string key in Request.Form.Keys)
    {
        LOG.WriteLine(key + ": " + Request.Form[key] + "<br/>");
    }
```

The LOG object is a StreamWriter going to a text file, which seems to work fine.

However the data in the file looks like this:

```
ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Main$Range_Data$STD_Code_Search: 01952<br/>
ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Main$Range_Data$Button2: Search<br/>
```

Fair enough, I then tried to use the following to retreive the data in C#

```
STD_Search = Request.Form["ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Main$Range_Data$STD_Code_Search"];
```

That does actually work and if I send STD_Search to the StreamWriter LOG I can see the entered value in my text file.

However if I then try and read a second value (in this case I'm trying to catch the value of Button2, so I can trigger specific behaviour if that button, rather than the original one, is clicked), using this code:

```
STD_Search = Request.Form["ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Main$Range_Data$STD_Code_Search"];
Button2_Clicked = Request.Form["ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Main$Range_Data$Button2"];
```

Then while the asp.net processes all appear to complete correctly (no errors or page crashes), the writing of the text file stops dead and no data at all is written.

**Questions**:

1. I'm sure I shouldn't have to include all the placeholder stuff
   (reading on here I gather that's part of the underlying framework
   and asp should in fact just present me with the named variables, the
   same as a Perl or PHP system would do with a plain HTML form), any
   pointers as to why that might be happening and if there's anything
   else I should be doing to process / extract the data?
2. Why does it all drop dead when I try and read in a second variable,
   despite working (for some large values of working) when I only read
   in one?
3. Are there any recommended books on asp.net and C#?  I have
   Sitepoint's "Build your own asp.net 4 website using C# & VB", which
   has helped a bit but isn't so useful for trying to take someone
   else's code apart and re-build it.

**Prior research**: I've done extensive searching on this, however most of the answers I've seen so far have been related to people using asp.net to process data submitted from external sites, etc, or by scripts using post directly.  All the sites I've looked at for tutorials on asp.net appear to say I should just use Request.Form["variable_name"], so there appears to be something else going on here.

Comment: Instead of posting this question here, you'd do far  better to read a basic ASP.NET tutorial. You can find many of these at http://asp.net.

Comment: You have 2 reasonable paths forward: 1) commit yourself to learning ASP.NET. There are plenty of online courses that will give you the basics at least. 2) Subcontract this to someone how knows ASP.NET. Right now you are overthinking this. You must learn .NET and use the .NET stack to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Obviously ASP.NET does a few things differently than you are used too, you just have to wrap your head around the way it works. You are basically butting heads with the ViewState model, which abstracts of lot of stuff, for better or worse. Also, not that it's an option for this legacy application, but ASP.NET MVC probably works a little closer to the way you are expecting.

Comment: Another note, the variable/control naming in your example would be considered "non-standard". Microsoft (and the community in general) recomends PascalCase or camelCase with no leading qualifier (aka no Hungarian notation). So "STD_Code_Search" should probably be CodeSearch or similar. Also, if you ever need to programmatically know the client id of the control (the funky name asp.net gives a control), you can use the ClientID property, ie STD_Code_Search.ClientID. Good luck!

Comment: @cadmium: Ta for the tips, there's clearly a layer in this I'm not getting, more to study, as ever!  Re naming, I was just copying what the original developers did to keep things consistent (I've previously worked on big Perl systems where every developer used a different naming / style convention - arrghhh! :) ), but will bear that in mind in future / new work.  In this case an "STD Code" is a thing ("Standard Telephone Dialing Code" ISTR), so that should presumably be StdcodeSearch in PascalCase.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: I've tried looking at on-line tutorials but they all assume you're using Visual Studio, whereas I'm attempting to edit the code directly on the server (well, a development site on a subdomain).  I need something that'll let me come at it from a "code" POV instead of assuming a full dev suite.  But somehow I'd missed asp.net as a website before, will have a look, thanks!

Comment: @user1818857, no problem, I know it's a weird system, especially if you know another web framework. Also, I would vote StdCodeSearch, though there's a case for stdCodeSearch as well, depending how you view protected variables.

Comment: @Pyromancer: the purpose of a tutorial isn't to help you solve the problem in front of you. It's to teach you enough about the platform so that what's in front of you isn't a problem. If you don't _have_ Visual Studio, go get the Express version to follow the tutorials. You would very quickly get to the point where they show you how _events_ work on _controls_, which abstracts away the entire `Form["Button1"]` business.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using code-behind to do all this stuff. It will make it easier.

```
string searchText = STD_Code_Search.Text;
```

And to to know if a button was clicked, you would do

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
```

And have it processed

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //button2 was clicked
}
```

Asp.Net is an event-driven framework, not like PHP or JSP. [Pick a good book on Asp.Net and read](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/). Most of the things you were trying to do have been handled for you by Asp.Net.

Comment: Oops - should have said this does use code-behind, the web page bits are in aspx files and the code in identically named aspx.cs ones.  I thought that was standard for asp.net (as opposed to classic asp which I've dabbled in and seems very similar to php?).

However I'd not thought of the event-driven angle, that actually makes a few things that were puzzling me clearer, ta for that.

Answer (score 1):

The `Request.Form` collection is only used when you want to access "raw" POST body contents directly. ASP.NET WebForms operates an abstraction layer which means you shouldn't normally need to use this collection.

Instead access submitted values by their parent controls. In this case the control is known as "STD_Code_Search" (an egregious violation of .NET's naming and style conventions, but I digress). Assuming you're using Visual Studio's tools, there will be an auto-generated file with the same name as your *.aspx file with the suffix "designer.cs" that will contain a class field called "`protected TextBox STD_Code_Search;`". All you need to do is access this field. Note that this field will only be populated after the `Init` page event.

```
string search = STD_Code_Search.Text;
```

Comment: Not using Visual Studio, rather editing the existing .aspx and .aspx.cs files on the server (dev copy of live site, of course).  There aren't any *.designer.cs files anywhere in the system that I can see, just the .aspx[.cs] ones and the general.cs in the app_code directory.  I'm copying the naming convention of the original authors for consistency for the time being, but as I commented to @cadmium above, will bear the correct conventions in mind for any all-new pages.  Assuming I get that far! :)

Comment: Oh yegods, you're using an `App_Code` project. Run while you still can!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try how its *supposed* to work?

You should have a protected variable for each form control in your .cs file. Newer versions of visual studio do this for you (when you add server side markup tags), but basically if you've no intellisense in the .cs file for the variable .g.

```
STD_Code_Search
```

If it's not declared, just do this at top of page:

```
protected TextBox STD_Code_Search;
```

now when you post back `STD_Code_Search.Text` *should* have a value

That as I've said is how it should work.

Unless there's some compelling reason to use Request.Form you shouldn't go there, but its worth knowing its whatever is wrriten in the "name" attribute on the client-side (hence that horrendous placeholder stuff). It can be overwritten to something more pretty (options based on your asp.net version).

Comment: While your advice is good, the emphasized words imply condescension, which doesn't help get your point across.

Comment: I was merely emphasising the moronic monolithic architecture that is the .Net page life cycle, as in, it's supposed to work like this, but more often than not you'll be smashing your face against the wall wondering why it isn't.. I wasn't condescending the OP Intentionally.

Comment: TBH I didn't know how it was supposed to work other than assuming it must have something vaguely in common with all the CGI stuff I've spent most of the last 14 years working on, but I gather from this thread it has differences I wasn't aware of.  Not using Visual Studio, just attempting to edit the existing files via Vim.  I'm basically a *nix guy, until now, never done Windows development unless you count a VB app I wrote nearly 20 years ago when I was designing 3D steelwork for a living.  Clearly lots of learn I wasn't even aware of, so ta for the info.